# provideCredentialWithoutUserInteraction method not getting called for autofill extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions, password-manager

I am developing password manager App with `autofill Credential Provider` extension.

method `provideCredentialWithoutUserInteraction` of `ASCredentialProviderViewController` is not getting called or not able to trace via breakpoint.

Code I have tried so far:

```
override func provideCredentialWithoutUserInteraction(for credentialIdentity: ASPasswordCredentialIdentity) {
        print(credentialIdentity.serviceIdentifier.identifier)
        let credToProvide = ASPasswordCredential(user: "udayyy", password: "paasssss")
        self.extensionContext.completeRequest(withSelectedCredential: credToProvide, completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

also not able to print any logs.
Can any one help me with how to debug this method?

What exactly I want show my custom password on top of the keyboard.(shown in below left image)

[image]

Comment: have you got any solution for this?? `provideCredentialWithoutUserInteraction` is not called when I tap on the quick type bar from native application, but it's working fine with  the browser.